# How to properly escape a JSON string for curl call in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: json, bash, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, escaping

I am writing a Jenkinsfile and in the middle of a stage to call an API with a CURL command, I have something like:

```
sh '''

accept_hdr="Accept:*/*"
fetch_mode_hdr="Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors"
content_type_hdr="Content-Type: application/json"

currentMonth="03"
currentYear="2022"
studentID="12345"

data="[{"month":"${currentMonth}","year":"${currentYear}","id":"${studentID}"}]"

curl -k -v --include --header "$accept_hdr" --header "$content_type_hdr" --header "$fetch_mode_hdr" --data "$data" -X POST http://testurl:555/path/api/${studentID}

'''
```

When I check my logs, it's showing this:

```
curl -k -v --include --header 'Accept:*/*' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' --data '[{currentMonth:03,currentYear:2022,studentID: 12345}]' -X POST http://testurl:555/path/api/12345
```

It's giving me an error saying:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('c' (code 114)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('c' (code 114)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

I see that this is because it is sending it as
`[{currentMonth:03,currentYear:2022,studentID: 12345}]`
instead of `[{"currentMonth":"03","currentYear":"2022","studentID":"12345"}]`

So I tried to escape the string online and used this instead: `[{\"month\":\"${currentMonth}\",\"year\":\"${currentYear}\",\"id\":\"${studentID}\"}]` but there was still the same error and it still was in the same format as before, without the double quotes.

Any idea how I can resolve this, I've been stuck for hours now trying to format it differently.

Comment: Escaping the double-quotes that're part of the JSON should work; try doing that and then put `echo "data is: $data"` right after it and see what it prints. BTW, the `curl` command appears to use `$md_payload` instead of `$data`; is that intentional?

Comment: @GordonDavisson That was unintentional, I had a typo and it autocorrected by accident. It should just be ```data```

Comment: @GordonDavisson, also whatcha mean by escaping the double-quotes that're part of the JSON? I thought I did that with my attempt: ```[{\"month\":\"${currentMonth}\",\"year\":\"${currentYear}\",\"id\":\"${studentID}\"}]```, or do you mean doing ```"\"[{\"month\":\"${currentMonth}\",\"year\":\"${currentYear}\",\"id\":\"${studentID}\"}]"\"```?

Could you post a response so I could see what you mean and try it, thank you!

Comment: I mean try `date="[{\"month\":\"${currentMonth}\",\"year\":\"${currentYear}\",\"id\":\"${studentID}\"}]"`, and then `echo "$date"`. That *should* work, and it works when I test it.

Comment: Nope, it's not working for me, the echo is showing something like:

```[{month:03,year:2022,id:12345}]```

Comment: Are you running that command directly in a shell or shell script, or is it going over an ssh connection, being `eval`ed, or anything else at all weird? Because the command I gave works (i.e. includes double-quotes in the output) when I test it in bash versions 3, 4, and 5, as well as zsh and dash, and both interactively and in a script. If it's not working for you, then *something* else is going on to complicate things. (Note: I glitched and used `date` instead of `data` as the variable name; that shouldn't matter as long as you echo the same one you set.)

Comment: This is ran via a jenkinsfile stage, but I call sh ``` ``` to write bash commands

Comment: @GordonDavisson it seems like when i do this in my jenkinsfile: ```test="{"'"test"'":"'"${currentMonth}"'"}"```

it shows as ```{"test":""$currentMonth""}```, now idea how to fix that variable to be read as what i set it to

Comment: Apparently Jenkins does its own weird preprocessing of escapes; see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4?permalink_comment_id=3156289). Try adding more escapes (e.g. `data="[{\\"month\\"...`, `data="[{\\\"month\\\"...`, etc).